# Slow execution of left join with or condition

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, left-join

I have a SQL query which joins another table on a or-condition, like this:

```
select a.id,b.id from a left join b on (b.prop1=a.id or b.prop2=a.id)

1026 rows in set (12.77 sec)
```

If I split the query into two, without or condition, it is much faster:

```
select a.id,b.id from a left join b on (b.prop1=a.id)
1026 rows in set (0.03 sec)

select a.id,b.id from a left join b on (b.prop2=a.id)
1026 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

Much faster, but then I manually have to combine the results from the two queries.

How come my initial query is so slow? What can I do to make it faster?

I'm using mysql 5.5.35

Comment: Would a `union` be faster? If you have the select on `a.id` and then `union` on `b.id` (all matching exactly)? Did you also define keys? or indexes?

Comment: Yes `or` is a killer. Even when they are part of where clause the indexes could not not be used. An alternative is to use `union all` with 2 queries where each joining condition is separated.

Comment: Why can't or doesn't this use the index? Is the query executor just not smart enough for that or is there some deeper reason?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34194658/694576

Answer (score 6):

Try and use a `UNION` in stead of an `OR`

```
select a.id,b.id from a left join b on (b.prop1=a.id)
UNION ALL
select a.id,b.id from a left join b on (b.prop2=a.id)
```

This should get it faster than the `OR`

Comment: No risk for duplicates here? Are you sure no rows have both b.prop1=a.id and b.prop2=a.id?

Comment: @jarlh UNION ALL removes duplicates.

Comment: Didn't know that... Are you really sure?

Comment: `UNION ALL` does not remove duplicates.  `UNION` does.

Comment: I told you... Adjust to (b.prop2=a.id and b.prop1 <> a.id) in second select.