# SQL JOIN WITH OR Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-server-2012

I have a table say **Cases**, which is using reference from **Workers** for three columns. Also there is one table **Company** to which workers belongs.

Below is the schema:

```
Cases [ CaseID, CaseNumber, Worker1, Worker2, Worker3 ] 
Workers [ WorkerID, ComapnyID]
Company [CompanyID, CompanyName]
```

Now I need case count for each company.
So is it possible to make one join with workers and map all **Worker1**, **Worker2** and **Worker3** columns? Is there any better option and performance impact?

Note: Two workers from one company can work on single case, or all the workers can be from different companies.

Comment: Firstly, the design is faulty. You should have a junction table like `CaseWorker (CaseID, WokerID)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although join conditions are commonly equality checks, there's nothing special about them - any valid SQL condition could be used for performing a join. In you case, an `IN` condition seems appropriate:

```
SELECT   CompanyName, COUNT(DISTINCT CaseID)
FROM     Company co
JOIN     Workers w ON co.CompanyId = w.CompanyId
JOIN     Cases ca ON w.WorkerId IN (ca.Worker1, ca.Worker2, ca.Worker3)
GROUP BY CompanyName
```

Comment: I like this one more than mine actually since it does what it says on the tin and nothing else.   Missing a group by though.

Comment: @IanYates Yikes! don't know what happened there. You are correct, of course. I've edited the `group by` in.

Comment: This is a nice, concise query! Cool!

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    C.CompanyID, C.CompanyName, count(distinct CaseID)
from Company C
    inner join Workers W
        on C.CompanyID = W.WorkerID
    inner join (
        select CaseId, WorkerId = Worker1 from Cases where Worker1 is not null
        UNION ALL
        select CaseId, WorkerId = Worker2 from Cases where Worker2 is not null
        UNION ALL
        select CaseId, WorkerId = Worker3 from Cases where Worker3 is not null
        ) CW
        on W.WorkerID = CW.WorkerID
group by C.CompanyID, C.CompanyName
```

Comment: See other comments about schema changes.  But if you can't change it you can at least cheat and unpivot (syntax I can never remember off the top of my head so I used the UNION ALLs instead) to make the table virtually

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend changing your schema a little like so:

```
cases - caseid, casenumber
workers - workerid, companyid
cases_workers - caseid, workerid
company - companyid, companyname
```

If you had it this way, you could write:

```
select companyname, count(*)
from company c
inner join workers w on c.companyid = w.companyid
inner join cases_workers cw on w.workerid = cw.workerid
group by companyname
```

EDIT:

If you cannot change schema, use some of the good queries already mentioned by other commenters. Here's my version:

```
with caselist (
  select worker1 as worker from cases union all
  select worker2 as worker from cases union all
  select worker3 as worker from cases
)
select companyname, count(*)
from company c
inner join workers w on c.companyid = w.companyid
inner join caselist cl on w.workerid = cl.worker
group by companyname
```

Comment: Agreed - the schema change is the right way to go.  But not always possible :(

Comment: @IanYates, yes, I agree with you. Let me edit my answer and add query that could be used with current schema

Comment: Sorry, but i can't change schema as it is already built and database is on production.

Comment: @dotNetAddict that is understandable. I have edited my answer appropriately keeping the query somewhat similar to the previous one I wrote. Also remember that someday you will have to change the schema; doing sooner might be a better option than doing it later.