# Joining two tables when dates mismatch

Tags: sql, teradata

I have Two tables Customer and Customer Address. Join criteria is on CustomerNo and Date. When date is not matching or not available on Customer Address table, I want to join with latest date available on the Customer Address

> ```
>    Customer Table              Customer Address Table
>     CustomerNo    Date        CustomerNo      Date       Addr
>     123          1/1/2017     123            1/1/2017   sample1
>     123          2/1/2017     123            2/1/2017   sample2
>     123          2/11/2017
>     123          3/1/2017
> ```

Expected output

> ```
>          Final Table 
>
> CustomerNo       Date      Addr
> 123             1/1/2017   sample1
> 123             2/1/2017   sample2
> 122             2/11/2017  sample2
> 123             3/1/2017   sample2
> ```

When Dates are not available in Customer Address , match with last available date.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe try use UNION ALL? Let's read about that from https://stackoverflow.com/a/34194725/8252554

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution. I haven't tested as I can't find a teradata compiler online.

Basically, the query gets the MAX record in the subquery and uses the Addr from max record if there isnt one already there for the date (See the COALESCE).

```
SELECT C.CustomerNo,
       C.Date, 
       COALESCE(CA.Addr, CMax.Addr) AS Addr
  FROM Customer C,
       LEFT JOIN Customer_Address CA
              ON (C.CustomerNo = CA.CustomerNo AND 
                  C.Date = CA.Date)
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT CustomerNo, Addr,
                         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerNo ORDER BY Date Desc) AS r_num 
                    FROM Customer_Address 
                   GROUP BY CustomerNo) CMax
              ON (C.CustomerNo = CMax.CustomerNo AND
                  CMax.r_num = 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is a subquery:

```
select c.*,
       (select top 1 address
        from customeraddress ca
        where ca.CustomerNo = c.CustomerNo and ca.date <= c.date
        order by ca.date desc
       ) as address
from customer c;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can use CASE expression in join condition, like this:

```
on c.date = case when ca.date = c.date then ca.date when [some logic] then [some result] end
```

as you mentioned that your ELSE logic is "last available date", you need to prepare this field somehow, for example in subquery.

But best solution is to split this complex join into few queries and union them all. It will work faster in Teradata.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM customer  c FULL OUTER JOIN address  a ON c.date=A.date WHERE a.date!=NULL
```

or try this

```
 SELECT * FROM customer  c FULL OUTER JOIN address  a ON c.date=A.date
```

try this query .if any make comment.